# Pyqt5 QTableWidget not emitting currentCellChanged signal when a cell containing a QComboBox is entered

Tags: pyqt5, signals, qtablewidget, qcombobox

I've subclassed QTableWidget to achieve a specific behavior. The first column of my table (idx=0) will contain QComboBoxes, and the second column (idx=1) will contain QLineEdits. This table will be used for user data input with an unknown number of required inputs. The default number of rows is 4. I have implemented logic so that there is always at least one row with a '' in the a QComboBox in the first column and there are never any fewer than four rows. If a user enters data and changes cells in the QTableWidget, the currentCellChanged signal fires and is connected to a checkAndExpand slot. This in turn should either add a row to the table, or remove rows that are blank - as long as there is at least one blank row.

All of this works if there is a QLineEdit in the first column. However, when I place QComboBoxes in the first column, the table's currentCellChanged signal does not fire, and checkAndExpand is not called.

Any advice here would be much appreciated.

As I mentioned above, I have a second subclassed QTableWidget that has QLine Edits (or rather, subclassed QLineEdits, called feedbackQLineEdit in this code) and that class/widget works as expected.

```py
class skiLabelTable(qtw.QTableWidget):
    """ Class for a table that is N rows long and two columns wide. each cell in the first column holds a combobox
    and each cell in the seond column holds a feedbackQLineEdit. The ski name is selected from the combobox and the label is typed
    (or loaded) into the second column. 
    
    There will always be at least one row with a blank in the combobox. The MINIMUM number of rows this widget can have is 
    four rows.
    
    this class emits a signal with a bound dict. The keys of that dict are the ski labels, the values are the ski names
    
    ONLY complete rows are emitted. If either column of a row is blank, it will not be in the dict"""
    
    #signals go here
    skiLabelDataChanged=qtc.pyqtSignal(dict)
    skiListChanged=qtc.pyqtSignal(list)
    
    def checkAndExpand(self,curRow,curCol,prevRow,prevCol):
        # Generate a list of data in the first column of data. 
        # if all cells have data, add a row and populate withe the appropriate widgets 
        # if there is EXACTLY 1 empty row, do nothing
        # if there are multiple empty rows at the end of the table, Remove those rows
        firstColData=[]
        #print(f'curRow = {curRow}')
        for i in range(self.rowCount()):
            firstColData.append(self.cellWidget(i,0).currentText())
        numBlank=firstColData.count('')
        print(firstColData)
        if numBlank==0: # There are now rows with a blank first column. Add one at the end!
            curRows=self.rowCount()
            #print(f'old Row Count is {self.rowCount()}')
            self.insertRow(curRows)
            #print(f'New row count is {self.rowCount()}')
            for j in range(self.columnCount()):
                if j==0:
                    self.setCellWidget(curRows,j,qtw.QComboBox())
                    self.cellWidget(curRows,j).addItems(self.skiList)
                    self.cellWidget(curRows,j).setMaxVisibleItems(10)
                    self.cellWidget(curRows,j).addItem('')
                    self.cellWidget(curRows,j).setCurrentIndex(-1)
                    self.cellWidget(curRows,j).currentIndexChanged.connect(self.checkAndEmit)
                else:
                    self.setCellWidget(curRows,j,tableQLineEdit(60))
                    self.cellWidget(curRows,j).textChanged.connect(self.checkAndEmit)
                firstColData.append('')
        blankIndicies=[x for x,val in enumerate(firstColData) if val=='']
        print(f'Last Blank Index = {blankIndicies[-1]}. Current Row = {curRow}')
        if curRow==blankIndicies[-1]:
            #ALL PREVIOUS ENTRIES HAVE BEEN FILLED OUT. WE JUST ENTERED THE LAST BLANK ROW. ADD ANOTHER!
            curRows=self.rowCount()
            #print(f'old Row Count is {self.rowCount()}')
            self.insertRow(curRows)
            #print(f'New row count is {self.rowCount()}')
            for j in range(self.columnCount()):
                if j==0:
                    self.setCellWidget(curRows,j,qtw.QComboBox())
                    self.cellWidget(curRows,j).addItems(self.skiList)
                    self.cellWidget(curRows,j).setMaxVisibleItems(10)
                    self.cellWidget(curRows,j).addItem('')
                    self.cellWidget(curRows,j).setCurrentIndex(-1)
                    
                    self.cellWidget(curRows,j).currentIndexChanged.connect(self.checkAndEmit)
                else:
                    self.setCellWidget(curRows,j,tableQLineEdit(60))
                    self.cellWidget(curRows,j).textChanged.connect(self.checkAndEmit)
                #set cell validation
                          
        if numBlank>1: #Remove all blank rows except the first blank row
            remRows=blankIndicies[1:len(blankIndicies)]
            #print(f'remRows = {remRows}')
            if len(remRows)>0:
                for r in reversed(remRows): #Start at the end so indexes don't get fucked. Don't remove rows if the table is less than 4 cells deep
                    if self.rowCount()>4:
                        self.removeRow(r) 
                    
    def checkAndEmit(self):
        #Function to take data from rows of table with a completely filled in row
        #and turn them into a dict. Names are Ski Labels are the keys. ski names are the vals
        retDict={}
        for i in range(self.rowCount()):
            if self.cellWidget(i,0).currentText()=='':
                continue
            elif self.cellWidget(i,1).text()=='':
                continue
            else:
                retDict[self.cellWidget(i,1).text()]=self.cellWidget(i,0).currentText()
        print(f'Emitting skiLabelDataChanged!!!: {retDict}')
        self.skiLabelDataChanged.emit(retDict)   
        
    def updateComboBoxList(self,newSkiList):
        #This funcion updates the values of the comboboxes in the first column of the widget. Before updating
        #this function makes a list of values currently in the comboboxes. If any of them are NOT in the
        #newSKiList, it gets added to self.skiList. This function will set the current value of any combobox
        #to '' unless there was a value in that combobox before this function was called. 
        
        #MAKE A LIST OF CURRENT ENTRIES:
        firstColData=[]
        #print(f'curRow = {curRow}')
        print(newSkiList)
        for i in range(self.rowCount()):
            firstColData.append(self.cellWidget(i,0).currentText())
        uniquevals=list(set(firstColData)) 
        #print(uniquevals)
        #are there any uniquevals currently in the comboboxes that are not in the new ski list?
        addvals=[x for x in uniquevals if x not in newSkiList]
        #print(addvals)
        for v in addvals:
            if v=='':
                continue
            else:
                newSkiList.append(v)
        #remove blanks - we'll add these at the end
        #print(newSkiList)
        newSkiList=[x for x in newSkiList if not x=='']
        #print(newSkiList)
        #print(type(newSkiList))
        for i in range(self.rowCount()):
            self.cellWidget(i,0).clear()
            self.cellWidget(i,0).addItems(newSkiList)
            self.cellWidget(i,0).addItem('')
            if i<len(firstColData):
                if firstColData[i]=='':
                    self.cellWidget(i,0).setCurrentIndex(-1)
                else:
                    self.cellWidget(i,0).setCurrentIndex(newSkiList.index(firstColData[i]))
            else:
                self.cellWidget(i,0).setCurrentIndex(-1)
                
    def updateSkiList(self,newSkiList):
        if self.skiList==newSkiList:
            print('do nothing')
        else:
            #get a list of unique vals currently entered. Add them as a union with the new list. 
            firstColData=[]
            for i in range(self.rowCount()):
                firstColData.append(self.cellWidget(i,0).currentText())
            uniquevals=list(set(firstColData)) 
            #are there any uniquevals currently in the comboboxes that are not in the new ski list?
            addvals=[x for x in uniquevals if x not in newSkiList]
            newSkiList=list(set(addvals+newSkiList))
            #remove blanks, if any
            newSkiList=[x for x in newSkiList if not x=='']
            self.skiList=newSkiList
            self.skiListChanged.emit(newSkiList)
            
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.skiList=[]
        self.setRowCount(4)
        self.setColumnCount(2)
        verticalHeader=self.verticalHeader()
        horizontalHeader=self.horizontalHeader()
        verticalHeader.setVisible(False)
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Ski Name','Ski Label'])
        for i in range(self.columnCount()):
            if i == 0:
                horizontalHeader.setSectionResizeMode(i, qtw.QHeaderView.Stretch)
            else:
                horizontalHeader.setSectionResizeMode(i, qtw.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents) 
        for i in range(self.rowCount()):
            for j in range(self.columnCount()):
                if j==0:
                    self.setCellWidget(i,j,qtw.QComboBox())
                    self.cellWidget(i,j).addItems(self.skiList)
                    self.cellWidget(i,j).setMaxVisibleItems(10)
                    self.cellWidget(i,j).addItem('')
                    self.cellWidget(i,j).setCurrentIndex(-1)
                    
                    self.cellWidget(i,j).currentIndexChanged.connect(self.checkAndEmit)
                else:
                    self.setCellWidget(i,j,tableQLineEdit(60))
                    self.cellWidget(i,j).editingFinished.connect(self.checkAndEmit)
        self.setMinimumWidth(360)               
        self.resize(self.sizeHint())
        self.currentCellChanged.connect(self.checkAndExpand)
        self.skiListChanged.connect(self.updateComboBoxList)
```

Comment: The `currentCellChanged` doesn't work well with cell widgets, because they can consume mouse/focus events that are not directly handled by the view. You should consider using a custom item delegate, return the proper editor in `createEditor()` and always call `openPersistentEditor()` for new rows/columns.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I've yet to use item delegates or editors as you suggest above. I'll do some research and (hopefully) update here with working code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm including an answer to my question. Many thanks to @musicamante. I'm leaving quite a bit of code out for brevity and relevance to the question I originally asked. The code here creates a qComboBox editor with static data. Eventually, I will need to make this more flexible (likely by creating separate delegates for columns that get comboBoxes and connecting data from the table model to data in the delegate)

```py
class testerTableDelegate(qtw.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        if index.column()==1:
            editor=qtw.QComboBox(parent)
            editor.addItems(['M','F','N'])
            #editor.currentTextChanged.connect(lambda value: self.currentIndexChanged(index, value))
        else:
            editor = qtw.QLineEdit(parent)
        if index.column()==1:
            editor.setValidator(sexValidator())
        elif index.column()>1:
            editor.setValidator(qtg.QIntValidator())
        return editor

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        value = str(index.model()._data[index.row()][index.column()])
        if isinstance(editor,qtw.QLineEdit):
            editor.setText(value)
        elif isinstance(editor,qtw.QComboBox):
            value = index.model().data(index, qtc.Qt.EditRole)
            if value:
                editor.setCurrentIndex(editor.currentIndex())            

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        if isinstance(editor,qtw.QLineEdit):
            model.setData(index, editor.text(), qtc.Qt.EditRole)
        elif isinstance(editor,qtw.QComboBox):
            model.setData(index,editor.itemText(index.row()),qtc.Qt.EditRole)

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, option, index):
        editor.setGeometry(option.rect)
```